# dynamic_reconfigure headers re-generated

Tags: make, rosmake, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I'm experiencing a small but irritating problem with dynamic_reconfigure.

Every single time I run make or rosmake all the reconf header files get re-generated so it causes all my nodes that use them to be re-compiled even though I did not modify any of them.

At first I thought that the problem is with the end .cfg file:

```
exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "dynamic_tutorials", "Tutorials"))
```

So I made sure that they are all correct but they still get regenerated every single time.

I'm running on Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS Electric.

Anyone faced this problem before?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33587/dynamic_reconfigure-headers-re-generated/) by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-09**:
Is this with Fuerte or Electric? What operating system?

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-05-09**:
I've had this problem in electric. I never did get around to figuring it out, or filing a bug.

**Comment by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on 2012-05-09**:
Sorry for the trivial mistake, updated post with info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm experiencing the same issue. I solved it by adding a guard to the beginning of the .cfg file, which checks whether the *Config.h file was generated after the last modification of the .cfg file. If this is the case the script is terminated without generating any files.

It looks like:

```
import os

me = os.path.realpath(__file__)
cpp_header = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(me), "cpp", "dynamic_tutorials", "TutorialsConfig.h"))

if os.path.exists(cpp_header) and os.path.getmtime(me) < os.path.getmtime(cpp_header):
  exit(0)
```

---

Originally posted by [christiank](https://answers.ros.org/users/1553/christiank/) with karma: 113 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on 2012-07-04**:
Please contact the authors so they can apply this patch to the next version of dynamic_reconfigure.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure

**Comment by [christiank](https://answers.ros.org/users/1553/christiank/) on 2012-07-05**:
ok, corresponding ticket is here: https://kforge.ros.org/dynamicreconfig/trac/ticket/5

**Comment by [klapow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2577/klapow/) on 2012-07-07**:
Thanks for the ticket, this will be fixed in the upcoming release of dynamic_reconfigure, if you want you can get it now at https://kforge.ros.org/dynamicreconfig/hg